# PhP input value as date

Tags: php

```
Order date <input type="text" name="inputReqDate" value=<?php Required date <input type="date" name="inputReqDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yy"> ?>>
```

I am very new to php, I do not intend to use the language very much at all so feel it unnecessary to learn just for this one application, sorry if that sounds abit snobby xD

I am attempting to show a input text box that has today already in its value. I have attempted but feel although what I have done is completely wrong. Please give me a hand, Sorry for being a newb :3

Comment: If you're not going to use PHP, why don't you use javascript instead to add the wanted value?

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is:

```
<input type="text" name="inputOrdDate" value="<?php
echo date("d/m/t");
?>">
```